# Managed struct being sent into an unmanaged function

Tags: c++-cli

```
int atClass1::read_file
(String^ file_path, /* Path tofile */
 HdfCallVars % ret_vals)
```

This is my function. Within it I have lots of native c++ code. I ran into a serious problem though

```
/* Iterate through the links, filling in needed data as discovered. */
  io_err = H5Literate (group_id, H5_INDEX_NAME, H5_ITER_NATIVE,

               &i, get_sonar_data, (void*)& ret_vals);
```

will not compile! Says ret_vals is managed and I can't do pointerey ampersandey stuff to it. Am  I in trouble? Or is there a way out of my dilemma? The H5 function is a call into the HDF5 library.
thanks,
saroj

Answer (score 0):

In .Net there is no guarantee that an object will remain on it current memory position as the garbage collector will "compact" the heap space when it wants to.

To get a native pointer to a managed object you should "pin" the object:

```
pin_ptr<HdfCallVars> pinned = &ret_vals;
io_err = H5Literate (group_id, H5_INDEX_NAME, H5_ITER_NATIVE, 
                        &i, get_sonar_data, (void*)pinned);
```

Note that the pointer will be unpinned after the variable `pinned` goes out of scope, if H5Literate stores the pointer for future use, you should pin the value using System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle, like this:

```
GCHandle ^handle = GCHandle::Alloc(ret_vals);
io_err = H5Literate (group_id, H5_INDEX_NAME, H5_ITER_NATIVE, 
                        &i, get_sonar_data, (void*)handle->AddrOfPinnedObject());
```

When you don't need the pointer anymore, you should free it:

```
handle->Free();
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the detailed response -- I will try it out right now! Many many thanks!saroj

Comment: GreenBoxal, I need H5LIterate to fill in my ret_vals. Is it going to do that, the way you write it in example 2? (example 1 wouldn't compile). How do I access ret_vals again after the call to the H5 function? thanks, saroj

Comment: Why example don't compile? Try to use cli::pin_ptr, both examples should write to ret_vals and you can access it normally